# htaccess - redirect all requests within subdirectory, except if a requested file exists

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdirectory, file-exists

I'm developing an app in php, and I need to set up a pretty broad .htaccess redirect. I did some reading and tried to write the RewriteConds myself, but it's a bit above my paygrade - I'm hoping someone with more experience can help. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- The app is contained in `www.example.com/app/`. Don't redirect anything above this directory.
- Some files exist in this directory that will need to be accessed. Currently these are `/app/includes/*` and `/app/sb_pages/*`. This will change and expand in the future, so I need an elegant solution that encompasses all existing files. It's fine if the redirect triggers within these directories when a file isn't found - all I care about is being able to access the files within without the redirect triggering.
- All other requests should be redirected to `/app/index.php`, with the trailing url passed in the querystring. For example, a request to `/app/path1/path2/` should redirect to `/app/index.php?path=path1/path2/`
- The redirect should not be transparent. When the user requests `/app/path1/path2/`, I want them to believe they have remained there. They **should not** see the url change to `/app/index.php?path=path1/path2/`.

Just for added clarity, here's a few cases to elaborate:

- `/app/includes/sidebar.php` should not redirect.
- `/app/includes/nothing.html` does not exist - redirect is OK
- `/app/path1/path2/` should redirect to `/app/index.php?path=path1/path2/`. User should still see their current URL as `/app/path1/path2/`.

I hope I've explained it clearly and pre-empted most questions. If you need clarification, please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this to your .htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^app/(.*)$ /app/index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note that if you want accesses to existing directories (as opposed to files) to also not be redirected, add a `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` above the rule.

Comment: That must have been what I was doing wrong - I was trying to write a .htaccess to put in /app, not in the root. Works like a charm, thanks!